# How to add more image on imageview

Tags: android

I'm stuck, and don't have any solution to fix
    The problem is that, i have a gridview and i want to add more image on it.
    I use new Adapter class with by code below.
    But I want to add 2 button and it overlap together

```
I use  LinearLayout for this


@Override
        public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            ImageView imageView;

              if (convertView == null) {
                 imageView = new ImageView(context);
                 imageView.setLayoutParams(new GridView.LayoutParams(85, 85));
                 imageView.getLayoutParams().width = 200; 
                 imageView.getLayoutParams().height = 200;   
                 imageView.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.FIT_XY);
              } 
              else 
              {
                 imageView = (ImageView) convertView;
              }
                 imageView.setImageResource(imageId[position]);


              return  imageView;
        }
```

Comment: basicily ImageView can only set Image Once, so if yout need to showing may images, you can use many ImageView or you can use Drawerlayout CMIW

Comment: if use Drawerlayout , i can't resize for every image:
ex: img 1 = 50x 50
 img 2 = 100 x 100 .. etc
after init imageView, i see 2 image same.
mys code:
 Resources r = getResources();
Drawable[] layers = new Drawable[2];
layers[0] = r.getDrawable(R.drawable.img1);
layers[1] = r.getDrawable(R.drawable.i,mg2);
LayerDrawable layerDrawable = new LayerDrawable(layers);
testimage.setImageDrawable(layerDrawable);

Comment: nstead of using `ImageView` use `LinearLayout` with inherited `ImageViews`